# How to avoid XLConnect's readWorksheet automatically rounding cells

Tags: r, xlconnect

I am using package XLConnect's function `readWorksheet()` to read in every sheet of an excel file. Hereby I noticed that numbers get automatically rounded to 0 or 2 digits after the comma. Is there an explanation for this behaviour and/or an option to avoid rounding when reading in?

I am using the following code:

```
wb <- XLConnect::loadWorkbook(filepath) # load a workbook
lst <- XLConnect::readWorksheet(wb, sheet = getSheets(wb)) # load all worksheets
```

Comment: You could try `lst <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "Sheet1", colTypes = c(XLC$DATA_TYPE.NUMERIC))` or something in that fashion.. What is the format of the cells if you open them in Excel? Perhaps changing the format (e.g. number of decimal points) of a column in Excel changes how R imports the data.

Comment: The cells in excel have format "number". 
Specifying `colTypes` does not help. When I specify them to numeric, values get rounded to 0 digits after the comma.

Comment: Are you sure the values are changed, not just the display of the values? How are you displaying the values in R?

Comment: Yes, the values are changed. I compared it using ´read.xlsx2()´ and ´options(digits = ...)´

Comment: 'read.xlsx2()' unnecessarily introduces a new complication in the form of another package (xlsx). You mention 'options(digits=)' so I guess you are displaying values in R using 'print'; 'digits=' controls the total number of digits, not the number of decimals. If any of your numbers have many digits before the decimal then print may fail to display all stored digits after the decimal. I have just tried your exact code and am seeing many digits after the decimal - no truncation. I cannot reproduce your stated problem.

Comment: As @user20637 already suggests, you may just be misled by R's printing of  numeric values. `options(digits = ...)` controls the number of digits to print. Another possibility is that some your numbers are converted to `character` because some cells (in the same column) are actually text formatted - in this case the formatting of the cell is taken into account.

Comment: Thanks for your answers so far. I am sure that the rounding is not due to R's printing behaviour.
@MartinStuder Your second guess seems very likely. Probably most of the columns are converted to `character`, since they have text elements in it.
I found another question regarding the same issue [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291626/how-can-i-import-all-the-decimal-places-in-a-mixed-type-column-with-xlconnect-an)
Do you happen to know if there is better option than the suggested workaround of reading in all the data twice?

Comment: @user116 There shouldn't be a need to read the worksheet twice. If you know the data types you are expecting just specify colTypes, possibly in combination with forceConversion = TRUE.